# fetching a link from Dev tools -> resources -> media in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, developer-tools

I'm trying to use JavaScript to fetch a link each time I open a page on a specific website.

Each page has a media element, that I can find the link to in the Resources/Frames/'name'/Media section of the developer tools. I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically fetch these media links through JavaScript. Here is how it looks in Chrome when I inspect element on a page, I want to dynamically fetch a link like this one.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}

function isMedia(link) {
    var mediaType = ["mp3", "mp4"];
    for (var i = 0; i < mediaType.length; i++) {
        if (endsWith(link, mediaType[i])) {
            return link;
        }
    }
};

var allLinks = $('a').map(function (i, el) { return $(el).attr('href'); });

$.grep(allLinks, isMedia)
```

Comment: hmm that doesn't seem to work. I'm trying on this link here. Play the song then inspect element and try.

https://soundcloud.com/tokimonsta/tinashe-ft-schoolboy-q-2-on